# Adding external library to vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am new to web development scene and recently started to dive into it, still getting a hang on how stuff are wired up in the background process by webpack.

I am trying to get wow.js which I installed by npm to work in all my Vue components. So I was wondering how do I include wow.js globally, such that all my future Vue component will be able to use `wow`?

I included the following in my `index.html`, but it didn't work.

```
<script src="node_modules/wowjs/dist/wow.min.js"></script><script>new WOW().init();</script>>
```

But when I do the following, which fetches it from a CDN, it works.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/0.1.12/wow.min.js"></script><script>new WOW().init();</script>>
```

Although it works if I use the CDN method, but I want to find out the proper way to include npm installed dependencies

**webpack.base.config**

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you create your project? Using the vue-cli? If that is the case you can just type `import packagename from 'packagename' and you should be able to use it. If you didnt use the vue-cli. So: import wow from 'wowjs'. Try that, and if it doesnt work you may need to provide your webpack.config.

Comment: Yes, I used vue-cli with webpack. On my `main.js` have tried `import Wowjs from 'wowjs'`, it throws the error ` http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars  'Wowjs' is defined but never used`. Included my webpack config. Seems to be linting error but I am not sure whats the best practice here

Comment: You need to make a call to wow in your code, or it will throw that error (actually, it's more of a warning - you code is still working and valid, the warning is to help you avoid unused variables). Try using the variable, and the warning should go away. For example, `const wow = new WowJs({ /* settings .. */ }); wow.init()`. Now use have used the variable, the linting error will go away. You may need to type `const wow = new Wow` instead - try both, I'm not that familiar with wowjs and how it exports from the module.

Comment: I keep getting the error `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_wowjs___default.a is not a constructor` no matter what combination I try. What gives?

Comment: Doesn't look like WowJS presents itself as a module ~ https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/155

Comment: So as I understand webpack correctly, it packs all my dependencies (modules) into 1 single module (bundle.js). Therefore if WowJS does not present itself as a module, there's no way I can tell webpack to include it as part of my dependencies? I am currently grabbing it down via its CDN link and find it to be very precise, just need to add a line to index.html. Furthermore, grabbing it via CDN is probably a better idea than to host it myself? Not that it wlll make a huge difference if I am also using a CDN myself too. What do you suggest?

Comment: What you said it correct - you are understanding webpack correctly, and because it does not export anything, webpack/node cannot import anything. The idea of webpack is to package it all up, not have duplicate modules, minify etc etc - so yes, it's better to have webpack manage everything for you. Take a look at the comments in the github issue, it looks like some people got it working. 

I recommend not spending too much time on this kind of thing, during dev it's okay to use a cdn, but you'll want to package it up eventually.